# Killing entire process tree in ruby

Tags: ruby, process, kill

So I'm working on some background task and I ended up having to spawn a child processes (using a binary provided by another team). At some point I want to stop such a process if it times out.

Seems straightforward enough.

```
def run!(command, timeout)
  Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
    stdin, stdout, wait_thr = Open3.popen2e(command)
    @pid = wait_thr.pid

    # ... boring and irrelevant...
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  Process.kill 'TERM', @pid
  Process.wait pid

  raise
end
```

Now I also quite like prepending my command with a call to `time`. Nice logs and all. This makes a command something like this (MacOS)

```
gtime -f 'Time spent %E memory used %M' some/binary --with parameters"
```

And so my process tree becomes something like this

```
ruby (my background job)
 \__ gtime
      \__ some/binary
```

Of course now when I kill the child process, only `gtime` is killed, the binary lives on.

1. If I had control over the executable I'm using as the immediate child, I could probably handle `TERM` and kill its immediate children processes. But it's `time`/`gtime` so I obviously don't. But maybe there's some arcane parameter?
2. The [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Process.html#method-c-kill) mention process groups but of course the children share the same process group as my parent process. Is there a way to spawn a process in a new process group thus making the "kill the entire process group" option viable?

I also could probably parse the `ps` output, build a process tree and traverse it killing processes one-by-one, but it seems a bit overkill (sorry). Is there something really basic I'm missing here?

Comment: "it seems a bit overkill (sorry)"  no apology necessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start the process in a new *process group* by passing `pgroup: true`: (see the docs for [`Process.spawn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Process.html#spawn-method) for available options)

```
stdin, stdout, wait_thr = Open3.popen2e(command, pgroup: true)
```

The whole process group can then be [`kill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Process.html#kill-method)-ed via its process group ID by prepending the signal with a minus sign:

> If *signal* is negative (or starts with a minus sign), kills process groups instead of processes.

```
pgid = Process.getpgid(wait_thr.pid)
Process.kill '-TERM', pgid
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by 'missing something basic'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the output of `ps`, you might want to look at [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep). Doing a bit of detective work and [discovering some code](https://github.com/grosser/parallel/pull/191/files), we find this convenient function:

```
# get child pids ordered by youngest descendants first
def child_processes(pid)
  pids = `pgrep -P #{pid}`.split("\n").map(&:to_i)
  pids.flat_map { |p| child_processes(p) } + pids
end
```

So let's say we have a process tree like this (example from my machine):

```
 9088 pts/3    Sl+    1:13  \_ ruby smtserver.rb
 9092 pts/3    Sl     0:41      \_ /usr/local/bin/chromedriver --port=9516
 9101 pts/3    Sl    10:36          \_ /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
 9111 pts/3    S      0:00              \_ /usr/lib/chromium-bro ser/chromium-bro
 9113 pts/3    S      0:00              |   \_ /usr/lib/chromium-bro ser/chromium
 9154 pts/3    Sl    14:06              |       \_ /usr/lib/chromium-bro ser/chro
 9187 pts/3    Sl     0:07              |       \_ /usr/lib/chromium-bro ser/chro
 9135 pts/3    Sl     2:08              \_ /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-bro
 9312 pts/3    Sl     4:44              \_ /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-bro
```

Now doing `child_processes(9092)`, we get this:

```
[9154, 9187, 9113, 9111, 9135, 9312, 9101]
```

And then you have enough information to individually kill the whole tree if needed.

In the case of `gtime`, it's enough to simply kill your `some/binary`, and gmtime will then exit by itself. Assuming `some/binary` is not creating more children, something like this should solve your problem:

```
rescue Timeout::Error
  Process.kill 'TERM', child_processes(@pid).last
  Process.wait @pid
```